# What is the reason behind not able to use this. keyword and datatypes like string and int in named constructor in Dart

Tags: dart, constructor

[image: Error Message]

Why in named constructor not able to use datatypes and this keyword? It shows Error:

> The parameter 'name' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
> Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.dart(missing_default_value_for_parameter)

Comment: Please remember to post your source code as text instead of using only screenshots. It makes it annoying to help you when you need to write the code from the picture into an editor.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, if nothing else is specified, the default value for optional named parameters is `null`. So what your code actually does right now is setting the variable `late String name` to `null` which is not allowed because of the type `String`. If you want to allow `null`, the type should be `String?`.

The `late` keyword is used in situations where you cannot set the variable when initializing the object and is just a promise to the Dart compiler that the variable will have a value when you are going to use the variable at some point. (the compiler will add a check to make sure the variable is actually given a value before use).

But `late` is not a way to allow `null` as a valid value.

Another problem in your code is that it does not really make sense to do:

```
person({this.name}) {
  this.name = name;
}
```

The reason is that `{this.name}` is already used for setting the variable `name`. When you later do: `this.name = name` then both `name` is pointing to the same variable in your object.

Based on the rest of your code I think you should remove the `late` keyword and instead use `required` to make sure the user of your class are specifying your named parameter. So something like this should work (also, please use `Person` instead of `person` for naming classes):

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;

  Person({required this.name, required this.age});

  void sayName() => print(name);
}

void main() {
  final p = Person(name: 'Mathew', age: 24);
  p.sayName();
  print(p.age);
}
```

I removed the named constructor `Person.age` since I don't think it makes much sense to make a `Person` without a `name`. If `name` and `age` is truly optional, you can instead change the types to `String?` and `int?` and remove the `required` keyword.

This will make it clear when using your class that these two variable can be empty and the user of the class should remember to check for possible `null` values.

I recommend reading more about Dart null safety feature starting here: https://dart.dev/null-safety